# what does "Yeah of course" represent?

Tags: meaning

In the following conversation, "yeah of course" represents what?

> J. What did you do last night?
>   M. Went to the cinema.
>   J. Oh really? What did you see?
>   M. Lord of the Rings, have you been yet?
>   J. No, it's difficult with the kids
>   M. Yeah of course.

Answers:

> **A.** Initiate
>   **B.** Follow up
>   **C.** Interaction
>   **D.** Respond
>   **E.** Pattern

Answer (score 1):

**F.** These answer choices are ambiguous, and this entire test was probably written either by a non-native speaker, or an English teacher who wants you to learn some *system* by rote, rather than learn how native speakers actually *use* the language.

"Yes, of course", implies *agreement*, or at least some degree of *sympathy* with the previous statement.

> J: I was really sick last night so I couldn't finish up my project as promised.  I'll try and finish it tonight.
>   M: **Yes, of course.**  You take care of yourself.

In this particular case, the correct answer will be *whatever the teacher **says** is the correct answer*.  When forced to learn a system, you have to follow its rules, even if they don't apply in the real world.